# ruby ternary operator syntax - spacing between operator

Tags: ruby, syntax, ternary

Is the following line proper ruby syntax?

```
session[:id]?'foo':'bar'
```

(Notice there is no spacing between the operators)

This line works with all the rubies I tried (>1.8.7) but I understand there can be a misunderstanding as the `?` can be part of a method identifier.

Shouldn't it be a syntax error to not put spaces arround the ternary operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the correct forms the ternary operator are when selector is the *indexed hash*, because the char combination `]?` is invalid for the same operator:

```
session[:id]?'foo':'bar'
session[:id] ? 'foo' : 'bar'
session[:id]? 'foo' : 'bar'
```

But if you omit the space after *just the a method* and *the question mark*, this will raise the syntax error:

```
session?'foo':'bar'
          ^
SyntaxError: unexpected ':', expecting $end
session? 'foo':'bar'
           ^
SyntaxError: unexpected ':', expecting $end
```

Comment: In other words, the first line with an _indexed hash_ is **correct ruby syntax**?

Comment: @PaulB. for a ruby interpreter, yes, for a programmer i'm not sure =)

Answer (score 1):

If a method identifier has `?` as part of it, you would require an additional question mark.

```
> array_variable.include?('itemA') ? 'yes' : 'no'
>= "yes"

> array_variable.empty? ? 'yes' : 'no'
=> "no"

> array_variable.empty? 'yes' : 'no'
  SyntaxError: (irb):10: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting end-of-input
```